# Canvas npm package v2.8.0 image getting pixelated when trying to drawImage , How to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

Hello I am using the [npm package canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) I am getting an issue while drawing another image on my background the image that I am trying to load is from an `API` source so its an `URL` the issue I am having is when I load that image its becoming greenish here is the [image link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/662341843861766164/845960114800558110/welcome-image.png) note I am using `node.js` and the image I am trying to load the size is **200px by 200px** I do not know why the 2nd image is behaving like this here is the code for my application.

```js
                    const loadImage = await Canvas.loadImage(data.clan.badgeUrls.medium)
            
                    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(755, 485)

                    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    const backGroundImg = await Canvas.loadImage("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/662341843861766164/845700894972706816/welcome-image.png")

                    context.drawImage(backGroundImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
                  
                    context.stroke();

                    context.strokeStyle = 'white'

                    context.strokeRect(30, 45, 690, 400);
                   
                    context.drawImage(loadImage, 60, 45);
```

Please tell me how can I fix this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when updating node canvas to a newer version. For me the problem was fixed after building node canvas again from source by executing the following command: `npm install --build-from-source`